# Op Amp as a buffer in lt spice for high voltage and high frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, buffer, high-frequency

I want to make a buffer which can drive my sine wave with an amplitude of ±25 volts and a frequency of 25 MHz. Which Op amp in LTspice should i use?

Comment: If you don't want to build it in real life, use an ideal one.

Comment: Use the ideal one

Comment: Or just use a VCVS.

Comment: @ThePhoton It's better to use a VCCS with a terminating resistor, instead, as it converges much faster and also behaves like a real buffer with real output impedance (warmly recommended by the manual), or with also a small enough capacitor to avoid possible discontinuitues (or steep transients). If a bandwidth is also needed, then `pipe`'s answer will do (or a `G+C` with `Rpar` specified). Of course, for simple enough schematics, a VCVS will do, no need for useless complications.

Comment: i need a real op AMP :( because i need to use it in my board...

Answer (score 3):

Use the one called `opamp`. Make sure to follow the advice in the description to add a `.LIB opamp.sub` statement:

[image]

The default bandwidth is too low, so you have to right-click on the opamp symbol and increase it. Set it to whatever you want. Here I used 1000 Meg:

[image]

Comment: hey! thank you so much :) but i need a real op AMP :( because i need to use it in my board... I found the THS3001 from ti and i think it should work